# in laravel , what is the differace between Route::resource and Route::get?

Tags: laravel, laravel-controller, laravel-resource

in laravel 9 , what is the difference between

```
Route::resource('/blog',[PostController::class);
```

and

```
Route::get('/blog',[PostController::class,'index']);
```

?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing Check the documentation. `Route::get()` defines a single route associated with a `GET` Request, while `Route::resource()` creates a bunch of Routes associated with `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc. for a single Model (Blog): https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers (Docs for 10.x, but should still be applicable to 9.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource route will generate all CRUD routes:

```
Verb          Path                       Action  Route Name
GET           /blog                      index   blog  index
GET           /blog/create               create  blog  create
POST          /blog                      store   blog  store
GET           /blog/{post}               show    blog  show
GET           /blog/{post}/edit          edit    blog  edit
PUT|PATCH     /blog/{post}               update  blog  update
DELETE        /blog/{post}               destroy blog  destroy
```

Second variant will generate only one GET route (first in the list)